# This is [adj] is what this is

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I guess I've just heard something like ***This is humiliating beyond belief is what this is*** on Larry David's "Curb Your Enthusiasm" [s03e05, around 17 min. mark]. Can anyone analyze the structure for me? Shouldn't it  be ***Humiliating beyond belief is what this is***?

Or did I mishear it?

Comment: "This is humiliating beyond belief" would be standard English.

Comment: Perhaps an alternative could be: *"Humiliation beyond belief is what this is"*. But I think I've actually seen this topic of yours, with a similar example sentence (where there is a subordinate clause instead of an expected NP for one of the elements), come up on (linguistics?) forum somewhere, . . . over the rainbow . . . but unfortunately, my head's a blank as to what their rationales were as to what was going on.

Comment: Note that, when a declarative content clause (such as "This is humiliating beyond belief") is subject or precedes the main verb of the main clause, then, the marker of clausal subordination "that" is obligatory--this is so that the reader/addressee won't initially perceive the content clause as the main clause. And so: "[***That*** *this is humiliating beyond belief] is [what this is]"*, but that version doesn't seem to work as well as the original (imo).

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like this could be related to the "[is is](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4338)" construction

Answer (score 3):

This is a kind of reduplication with the intent of intensification.

> [Reduplicated words or phrases](http://blog.dictionary.com/reduplication/) act as intensifiers — they are describing things that are somehow more real, true, intense, or strong.

While most reduplication is shorter, this is still repetition to intensify. Gommon reduplication would be *artsy fartsy* (rhyming reduplication), *teeny-tiny* (ablaut), *Teeny-teeny* (exact), *redder and redder* (comparative), *I'm up; I'm just not UP-up* (contrastive focus), etc. Hiberno-English uses reflective phrases: "We won the game, so we did."

The common structure for *This is humiliating beyond belief is what this is* is

> This is humiliating beyond belief.

By stating *is* three times (twice in *this is*), it's a way of saying

> This is *very, very* humiliating beyond belief. or This *really, really* is humiliating beyond belief.

*Beyond belief* makes the really and very sound almost superfluous, so a different way to emphasize what it *was* is to reduplicate the main verb.

> This is humiliating beyond belief **is what *this is***. (or **!**)

Why reduplication over straightforward communication? Sometimes it is to show to humor (this is how I would interpret your example.) Sometimes to be cute (*teensy-weensy*). Maybe because the speaker just finds reduplication to be the most accurate way to express his feelings about the thing.

Comment: Hmm, not so sure that the word "is" is what is being reduplicated for an intensifying effect. For the verb "is" seems to be functioning as the head verb in copular clauses: *"[This* **is** *humiliating beyond belief]* **is** *[what this* **is**]." Perhaps the word "this" is being reduplicated for that intensifying effect, or not.

Comment: I may be missing something but I feel your point is the speaker kind of chose to reduplicate as he saw fit. I can't shake the feeling that the "This is [adj] is what this is" structure could be found even in "The Red Badge of Courage". I mean, there's syntactically more to it than simple reduplication of a word to make it stand out, right?

Comment: @F.E. - Yes, I think maybe a better way to look at it is that *this* is the word that is being emphasized; I think, though, regardless of whether it's the essential *is* or the specific *this*, that we can agree that it's reduplication for intensification, am I correct? Or is there a better term for the example?

Comment: @jules - good point. Yes, I do believe he reduplicated as he saw fit. Maybe it's subtly idiomatic?

Comment: I agree with your that there does seem to be reduplication in the sentence, in the way it is worded. (But the "is" perhaps isn't stressed.) The two "this" helps for that effect, and could possibly be stressed by the speaker. Perhaps because the first element is a clause ("This is humiliating beyond belief"), which kinda reduplicates the clause of the last element ("what this is"), that is also providing some intensifying effect. But I'm mostly guessing here. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm kinda now seeing the reduplication in the clauses of the two elements, and that was probably one of the reasons why the first element is in the form of a clause, and not an NP. The last element sorta has this certain structure: "This is what?" as a sorta question, and the first element sorta echoes a similar clause structure when answering it: "This is humiliating beyond belief".

Comment: @F.E. - as I was thinking about this, I thought it has a Brooklyn Jewish feel to it. I have never seen Curb Your Enthusiasm, and didn't know who Larry David was (yeah, I know, but...). I just looked him up, and he was born in Brooklyn and is Jewish (I grew up within commuting distance of NYC). I'm thinking this has a cultural aspect to it.

Comment: Isn't the sentence an example of a cleft sentence in a way? PS. I've just remembered seeing something in the same vein, ie. "This is humiliating beyond belief is all". Possible? Correct?